# How do I actually pre/post-process RSpec example based on the arguments passed to describe or it

Tags: ruby, rspec, bdd, rspec2

Need some help understanding:

> In `rspec-2`, every example and example group comes with metadata
>   information like the file and line number on which it was declared,
>   *the arguments passed to `describe` and `it`*, etc. This metadata can be
>   appended to through a hash argument passed to `describe` or `it`, allowing
>   us *to pre and post-process each example in a variety of ways*.

https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/master/features/Upgrade.md — **«Metadata!»** section

I'd like to have the following shortcut:

```
describe 'DELETE destroy', :as => :admin do
  it 'destroys...' do
    # ...
  end
end
```

for

```
describe 'DELETE destroy as admin' do
  before { login_as :admin }

  it 'destroys...' do
    # ...
  end
end
```

Is metadata-based example pre/post-processing appropriate in the case or it was made for «external» things like *filtering*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this should work:

spec_helper.rb

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:each, :as => :admin) do |example|
    login_as :admin
  end
end
```

Then your spec should work as expected with the `:as => :admin` option. See also [this article](http://avsej.net/2011/rspec-metadata-trick/).

Comment: You're welcome. I didn't actually know about metadata in rspec, might try using it myself.